# rabbitmq inet_gethost reading ~50 times per second /etc/hosts file

Tags: linux, rabbitmq, gethostbyname

My task is to  reduce load on Linux machine running rabbitmq. First place in *top* is taken by `inet_gethost 4` ( there are two such processes, but one is constantly sitting on the top of the *top* ). I started analyzing that process with *strace* and it's showing huge number of opening and reading from */etc/hosts*. `strace -fp 4571 -e open 2> count && wc -l count` revealed over 50 reads of that file per second. Question is if that kind of behavior is normal or is this a result of badly configured rabbit or some networking settings.

Comment: Please explain what does this have to do with **C** excepting that Unixen are generally coded in C.

Comment: Also, perhaps you could affect this with modifying [`nsswitch.conf`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I was hesitating between **Linux** and **C** tags as this problem definitely touches some aspects  of system C programming

Comment: Also, load means nothing. CPU usage is a different thing though.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala What do you mean by "load means nothing"?